# Associating data with a user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

For my first ASP.NET MVC 3 application, I'm using the `aspnet_Users` and `aspnet_Roles` tables to provide authentication for my users and for a few roles.  That seems to work pretty well.  Additionally, I want to make associations between the logged-in user and rows in various tables.

As a concrete example, I've got a `Recipes` table which has columns specific to recipes (name, dates, attributes) as well as a `UserID` column.  That `UserID` column is currently a foreign key to a `Users` table in my IceCreamDB (NOT the `aspnet_Users` table in the aspnetdb) which contains various domain-specific information about users of the system.  So, it's easy enough to create a query that retrieves all of Matt's recipes, by creating a user in my Users table named Matt who has some integer UserId and then use that UserId during Creates and Updates to the `Recipes` table.  Great.

To tie the logged-in user "itsmatt" (from the aspnet_Users table) to my IceCreamDB's Users table UserId for Matt, I have a Guid column in IceCreamDB Users table which is filled in with the aspnet_Users Id (its a Guid) for the login.

IceCreamDB's Users table:

```
 UserId     1               // primary key used as FK for other tables 
 UserName   Matt
 Phone      555-1212
 Department Product Development
 Building   2-A
 Office     221
 UserGuid   7fc75a6c-7e32-43f3-be8c-be0122bf54cb // Guid from aspnetdb User table
```

And this works OK - as part of the user registration process, I create an aspnet_User, set up whatever roles (e.g., "Administrators", "Owners", "Production") are appropriate, and then create a user entry in the IceCreamDB Users table, copying the Guid into the new row.  This lets me log into the website and see my recipes or my orders.

But I feel I've home-brewed this solution and there's likely a better, different approach to doing this. I'd like some guidance on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I known, this is a quite common solution. The 2 other I'm aware of are using `aspnet_Profile` for simple settings, or editing the `aspnet_Users` table, which is not a good solution, because if you'd have more applications (`aspnet_Applications`) using the same `aspnet_Users` your end up having fields on that table which one application might use (not nullable) and the other doesn't.

In [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/storing-additional-user-information-cs) they are basically doing the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yeah, I wanted to avoid touching any of those aspnet_ table structures since that just felt like a bad thing to do.  Thanks for the link - I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2):

That's OK to me.  The Membership provider also works the other way around - it has a provideruserkey property  that's stored in the DB that would contain the UserId value of 1 in the aspnet_users table.

So if its good for Microsoft, it aught to be good for your scenario :-)

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It's easy to cobble together a poor solution when you work in a bubble and that's what I'm trying to avoid by throwing it out here on SO for folks to critique and suggest.

Comment: Yup, I understand.  That's how I would do it since you would typically have a 1 to 1 relationship in this scenario.  Or, use an intermediary table that sits in between the two, in case you want to support a one to many scenario.